# fluid link to pdf file when file is a fal object

Tags: typo3

is there a possibility to generate a download link to a pdf in a fluid template when the pdf file is a fal object?

I tried

- f:image which results in a converted picture
- f:typolink expects a string not an object
- f:typolink with file:{file.uid} as parameter results in wrong files because uid is not the uid of the file but the file reference
- f:typolink with file:{file.uidLocal} throws an error because uidLocal is protected ...
- f:typolink with file.originalResource.identifier results in a nearly correct url except that the file except that the storage folder is missing

Of course i could add the storage folder als string but it feels not correct. Is there any possibility to generate a normal download link in fluid of TYPO3 8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<a target="_blank" href="{image.originalResource.publicUrl}">Download Now</a>
```

Comment: Obviously not :-) Thats exactly what i looked for, thank you very much! I did not find it, because <f:debug>{file.originalResource} does not show a property namend publicUrl ...

Comment: You've gotta love the hidden properties of FAL objects - they are quite a mystery. Another fun tip, you can use {image.originalResource.name} if you want the name of the file. I've often had to use this instead of "Download Now" as per some client requests.